# Вывод json строк в php

Tags: php, jquery, json

Здравствуйте. Имеется код:

```
 <?
        include "../cfg.php";
        $select_all_raffles = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM raffles WHERE closed = "0" ORDER BY price DESC');
        echo '{"raffles_games": [';
        $status = "0%";
        $status_text = "0 / 2";
        while($row_all_raffles = mysql_fetch_array($select_all_raffles)) {
            if(!empty($row_all_raffles['player1']) && !empty($row_all_raffles['player2'])) {
                $status = "100%";
                $status_text = "2 / 2";
            } else if(!empty($row_all_raffles['player1']) || !empty($row_all_raffles['player2'])) {
                $status = "50%";
                $status_text = "1 / 2";
            }
            if($row_last_pls['id'] == $row_all_raffles['id']) {
                $last_or_no = ",";
            }
            $scoba = '"';
            printf("{".$scoba."id_raffle".$scoba.": %s".$scoba."width_percent".$scoba.":".$scoba."%s".$scoba."width_text".$scoba.":".$scoba."%s",$row_all_raffles['id'].",", $status.$scoba.",",$status_text.$scoba."}*проблемное место*");
        }
        echo "]}";
    ?>
```

Суть в том, что я хочу вывести строки из бд в json строки. Когда была одна строка всё работала, а чуть позже, когда я почти все сделал и накидал ещё строк в базу данных, строк начало выводиться больше и json получается примерно в таком формате:

```
{"raffles_games": [{"id_raffle": 2,"width_percent":"0%","width_text":"0 / 2"}{"id_raffle": 3,"width_percent":"0%","width_text":"0 / 2"}{"id_raffle": 5,"width_percent":"0%","width_text":"0 / 2"}{"id_raffle": 9,"width_percent":"0%","width_text":"0 / 2"}{"id_raffle": 4,"width_percent":"0%","width_text":"0 / 2"}{"id_raffle": 6,"width_percent":"0%","width_text":"0 / 2"}{"id_raffle": 7,"width_percent":"0%","width_text":"0 / 2"}{"id_raffle": 8,"width_percent":"0%","width_text":"0 / 2"}]}
```

Проблема была в том, что после каждого массива нужна запятая. Хорошо, я решил поставить запятую в *проблемном месте* (код 1). Но после проблема в том, что запятая ставиться в конце каждого массива т.е. и после последнего ( в чём, собственно, и ошибка ). Так вот подскажите, ребят, как мне сделать так, чтобы запятая после последнего массива не ставилась? Надеюсь, объяснил доходчиво. Спасибо!)

Comment: вы делаете какой-то совершенно ужасный костыль.......делайте массив с нужной структурой и потом используйте [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php), не мучайте себя

Comment: еще для общего развития `implode` есть

Answer (score 0):

Должно работать

```
$array2json = array();
while($row_all_raffles = mysql_fetch_array($select_all_raffles)) {

    if(!empty($row_all_raffles['player1']) && !empty($row_all_raffles['player2'])) {
        $status = "100%";
        $status_text = "2 / 2";
    } else if(!empty($row_all_raffles['player1']) || !empty($row_all_raffles['player2'])) {
        $status = "50%";
        $status_text = "1 / 2";
    }

    $raffle['id_raffle'] = $row_all_raffles['id'];
    $raffle['width_percent'] = $status;
    $raffle['width_text'] = $status_text;
    $array2json[] = $raffle;
}

echo json_encode(array('raffles_games'=>$array2json));
```